# Как узнать какой специальный(метод с двумя подчеркиваниями) вызывается при использовании какого - либо оператора

Tags: python, методы

К примеру, есть следующий код:

```
first_list = [1, 2]
second_list = [3, 4]
final_list = first_list + second_list
```

Вывод последней строки кода эквивалентен использованию специального метода `__add__`:

```
final_list = first_list.__add__(second_list)
```

Вот так я получу вывод всех аргументов и методов, доступных для этого объекта:

```
print(dir(final_list))
```

Есть ли возможность после операции сложения вывести конкретный специальный метод, который использовался в данном случае? Я знаю, что это `__add__` , но существует ли функция, которая возвращает специальный метод, который был использован в результате выражения?